# How to derive from/implement a C# class hierarchy in without code duplication

Tags: c#, design-patterns, class-hierarchy

I am faced with a C# design problem that C#'s limitations are making hard to achieve.  I need some sort of design pattern/strategy to rescue me.

I must create the archetypical set of abstract shape classes:  Base class `Shape` with derived classes `LineShape`, `RectShape`, etc.  Specific implementations will derive from these.  The problem is that I really need to use classes here, *not interfaces* and this is forcing me to duplicate a lot of code.

To illustrate:

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract int      Id           { get; }      // Unique ID 
    public abstract string   Name         { get; set; } // Shape name.  Defaults to the type of shape
    public abstract bool     IsLocked     { get; set; } // May the user change this shape in any way?
}

public abstract class LineShape : Shape
{
    public abstract Point P1 { get; set; }
    public abstract Point P2 { get; set; }
}

public abstract class CircleShape : Shape
{
    public abstract Point Center { get; set; }
    public abstract double Radius { get; set; }
}
```

When I start creating the derived implementations (`LineImpl`, `CircleImpl`, etc), I find that the implementations of the  `Shape` functions are identical for all the Impl classes, yet specific enough that I cannot implement them in the abstract `Shape` class itself.

So I need to find a way to share a common implementation of these function in my derived hierarchy.

In other words  `LineImpl` must derive from `LineShape`.  `CircleImpl` must derive from `CircleShape`, etc.  I cannot find a way to insert a `ShapeImpl` in there to handle the boiler plate stuff.  So I am forced to implement all those `Shape` functions over and over again, once in each Impl shape type.

I tried using generics to get my way out of this but unfortunately a generic class cannot specify its base class with a generic argument.   In other words, the following approach (which I might do in C++) does not work in C#

```
public class ShapeImpl<TBase> : T where T : Shape {  ... boiler plate implemented here)...}
public class LineImpl         : ShapeImpl<LineShape> { }
public class CircleImpl       : ShapeImpl<CircleShape> { }
```

So I am at a loss.  Is there some C# trick or design pattern that can get me out of this?  Or am I forced to implement the same functions multiple times?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227929/discussion-on-question-by-joe-how-to-derive-from-implement-a-c-class-hierarchy).

Comment: We'd already done that

Answer (score 2):

> yet specific enough that I cannot implement them in the abstract Shape class itself.

You also mentioned:

> I find that the implementations of the Shape functions are identical for all the Impl classes

I think that this is classic case of over-thinking for future implementation. if you say- the implementation is identical for all classes, I wouldn't bother too much over thinking for something in the future that may never arrive.
But, if you insist, you may implement it in the following way:

```
    public abstract class Shape
    {
        public abstract int Id { get; }      // Unique ID 
        public abstract string Name { get; set; } // Shape name.  Defaults to the type of shape
        public abstract bool IsLocked { get; set; } // May the user change this shape in any way?
        public abstract void Foo();
    }

    public abstract class SepcificShape : Shape
    {
        protected virtual void FooSpecific()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Specific Implementation");
        }
    }

    public abstract class LineShape : SepcificShape
    {
        public abstract Point P1 { get; set; }
        public abstract Point P2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class LineImp : SepcificShape
    {
        public override int Id { get; }
        public override string Name { get; set; }
        public override bool IsLocked { get; set; }
        public override void Foo()
        {
            base.FooSpecific();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I must admit I do not see how this approach changes things.  Your example derives the abstract base class LineShape from SpecificShape.  How then do I hide implementation details  (which must live in SpecificShape) from clients of LineShape?

The details do need to be hidden.  Unfortunately The need is here right now.  I must implement one set of these classes to wrap an existing, equivalent set of shape classes from an external SDK.  I cannot put these SDK details into the base classes.  Another set must use local implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve something similar to multiple inheritance in C# I can think of would be to use default interface implementations, e.g. like this:

```cs
    interface IShapeSdk
    {
        string GetNameSdk() => "Shape SDK name";
    }

    abstract class Shape
    {
        public abstract string GetName();
    }

    class ShapeImpl : Shape, IShapeSdk
    {
        public override string GetName()
        {
            return ((IShapeSdk)this).GetNameSdk();
        }
    }
```

This way all shapes will inherit from `Shape`, but only the external-SDK-shapes will inherit the common logic defined in `IShapeSdk`.

Not the cleanest approach, and a lot of C# developers are against the usage of this relatively new feature (which by the way is available only in C# 8 and above and .NET Core 3.0 and above).

Comment: A cool approach and one I had not considered.    But many of my interface members are properties and I'm using WPF which (I've learned the hard way) will not pick up default property implementations from interfaces.   I'm starting to think that maybe I'm just asking for too much here.  Because even if I could I go that way, I pity the poor developer who has to maintain this code after me and try to understand what  I was doing.   I'll give this a hard look but  -- worst case -- I suppose there are worse things than repeating boilerplate code 6 times.  Very much appreciate the effort you made